# Calling variable is not working

Tags: php

Im not even sure if these are called variables. But I am trying to call information from the database a different way than I usually do.

This is what is not working:

```
id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'], $con);
/* once the file is imported, the variables set above will become available to it */

 $select = ("SELECT * FROM shirts WHERE id = '$id' ");
 $result = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$id = $id;
$thumb = $row['thumb'];
$title = $row['title'];
$paypal = $row['paypal'];
$tags = $row['tags'];
$price = $row['price'];
}
?>
<div class="storeWrap">
<div class="thumbBox">
<a href="<?php $thumb ?>"rel="lightbox[<?php $id ?>]" title="<?php $title ?>"><img   src="<?php $thumb ?>" width="340px"></a>
 </div>
 <div class="descMain">
 <h2 align="left"><?php $title ?></h2><br />
 <div align="right"><?php $paypal ?> </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Any suggestions on why my first block of code doesnt work? The page loads but I do not get any errors and I do not see the shirt I am trying to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's typo. Be attentive while writing code. Put '$' before "id"

Answer (score 1):

Put '$' before "id" to make "id" a variable. Variables in PHP starts with '$' sign:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'], $con);
```

Here's a link about variables in PHP:

```
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add a `$` here:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'], $con);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

`id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'], $con);` 
This is typo? You missed the `$`.

Besides, you need echo the result, should like `<?php echo $title ?>`